# Supply arguments to program under gdbserver on MSYS

Tags: c++, gdb, mingw, msys, gdbserver

I needed to debug a program asynchronously, because it stalled, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> killed `gdb`, rather than interrupting the program (this is on MinGW/MSYS).

[Someone hinted](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2011-10/msg00199.html) that `gdb` wouldn't work on Windows in async mode, and indeed it didn't (with the `Asynchronous execution not supported on this target.` message), but that `gdbserver` would.

So I try:

```
$ gdbserver localhost:60000 ./a_.exe 0
Process ./a_.exe created; pid = 53644
Listening on port 60000
```

(Supplying the `0` as the argument, according to [how the manpage says it's done](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbserver-man.html).)

Then in another terminal:

```
$ gdb ./a_.exe
(gdb) target remote localhost:60000
Remote debugging using localhost:60000
0x76fa878f in ntdll!DbgBreakPoint () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (Remote target) exited with code 01]
```

While the original now looks like:

```
$ gdbserver localhost:60000 ./a_.exe 0
Process ./a_.exe created; pid = 53484
Listening on port 60000
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
Expecting 1 argument: test case number to run.

Child exited with status 1
GDBserver exiting
```

That is, my program thought that it got no arguments.

Is the manpage wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Yes! "Misleading" is a more fitting term. (Misleading, at least as it applies to this version of `gdbserver` on this platform.)

The first argument is literally the first argument (`argv`) given to the inferior. Normally this is the name of the executable. So, the following worked:

```
$ gdbserver localhost:60000 ./a_.exe whatever 0
```

That is, the manpage should have said, to be consistent:

```
target> gdbserver host:2345 emacs emacs foo.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not able to help you out with gdbserver,
but if you are just looking for a way to interrupt a program running in mingw/msys gdb
(Similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on linux)
take a look at at [Debugbreak](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Workaround_for_GDB_Ctrl_C_Interrupt)